# Remove a price info in basket+checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Woocommerce + the Woocommerce Gravity forms add-on on my website.
My issue is that when a customer fills out the product form (on the product page), and then gets to his basket to proceed to the checkout, there is a price info that shows on both pages that I don't want there.

To be more precise : the website sells packaged trips. For one trip, you have to choose from different options including the type of hotel (hostel/2*/3*/4*). The price of the package is XX corresponding to the cheapest option (hostel). Then if the customer chooses a 2* hotel for example, the price of the package goes up 100€. But I don't want the 100€ (which is the option's value) to show on the basket / checkout page. I only want his choice (2*) to show so that I know what he chose.

here is a picture showing what I mean :
http://tinypic.com/r/2v3llxx/9

and here is a link to the corresponding product page (but you'll obviously have to fake a purchase if you want to access the basket/checkout pages):
http://tinyurl.com/pzum42k

Any help would be great !!

Thanks in advance
G

Comment: You can use css to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 - Modify the woocommerce templates to change the output.**

The item variation data is outputted from `woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-item-data.php` in a `foreach` loop. You could check for the key and do a string manipulation to remove the part you don't want to output.

```
preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);
```

**Option 2 - Use javascript to remove part of the output**

The elements have a class (eg. `variation-Votrehbergement`) that you could use to grab the contents and do a string manipulation to remove the part you don't want to output.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    $( ".variation-Votrehbergement p, .variation-Chambre1 p").each(function( index,elem ) {
          $(elem).html($(elem).html().replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, ""));
    });
});
```

Comment: just seen your reply Tristan. Thanks so much for your time and expertise. You rock !!